# How do you open/close mysql connection multiple times?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using node with mysql and I have a route that does:

```
const mysql = require("./mysql");
router.post("/register_user", (req, res) => {
   mysql.register(req.body).then((result) => {
      // stuff
   });
});
```

mysql.js:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection("mysql://...");

exports.register = (req) => {
    const user = { name: req.name };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       // make sure user doesn't exist already
       connection.query('...', [user], (err, data) => {
         ...

         if (isNewUser) {
           connection.query('INSERT INTO USER...', user, (insertErr, rows) => {
             ...
             resolve(rows);
             connection.end();
           }
         }
       });
    });
}
```

This works perfectly when I register the first user in my app. But immediately after, if I log out (on the web app), then register a new user, I get an error saying:

```
Error: Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit.
```

Why doesn't this create a new connection?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the following NPM module [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)
If it is the case then could you simply use [MySQL pooling connections](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pooling-connections) ?

> Rather than creating and managing connections one-by-one, this module also provides built-in connection pooling using mysql.createPool(config).

So instead of calling `connection.end();` you would be calling `connection.release();` instead to return connection to the pool of open connections.